# How to declare and access global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

What Im doing wrong in the below code?

```
//File1.js
var arr = [];
function insertName {
    var name = "josh";
    arr.push(name);
    return name;
};
function validName(key) {
var index = arr.indexOf(key);
    if (index == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

var result = insertname();
exports.arr = arr;
exports.validName = validName;
```

```
//File2.js
var file1 = require("./File1.js");
var name = "josh";
var verify = file1.validName(name);
if(verify) {
cosnole.log("Valid name");
}else {
console.log("Error");
}

node File1.js
node File2.js
```

When Im executing File2.js, Im gettin undefined for arr[]. Can someone help me what Im doing in the below code

Comment: In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that module. -- http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: `validName` doesn't magically make its way into `file1` as a property; you'd have to export it.

Comment: Is this all the code or is there more that wasn't posted?  I copied your code in to files (fixed a couple of syntax errors) then ran it the nodejs command prompt and it worked file.

Comment: Thanks. It is working properly if I run using node. But same code if i run using Cluster module, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js modules retain the variables you declared at their top level, till the module is Garbage Collected or you manually delete them. If you look at your `File1.js`, you are exporting the array object, nothing else. So when you say

```
var file1 = require("./File1.js");
```

`file1` is just a reference to a JavaScript object which has an `arr` property. You can check this by printing the `file1`. The functions you created in `File1` are never exported. So, you can fix it like this*

```
exports = module.exports = {
    validName: validName,
    insertName: insertName
}
```

Now, you are exporting the functions and they can still access the `arr` variable. From `File2`, you can invoke `insertName` like this

```
file1.insertName();
if (file1.validName("josh")) {
    console.log("Valid name");
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}
```

<sub>* To know more about `exports` and `module.exports`, you can check [my blog post](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2014/03/nodejs-modules-and-exports.html) about this</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains mistakes change your code like below

File1.js

```
  var arr = [];

  function insertName() {
        var name = "josh";
        arr.push(name);
        return name;
  };

  function validName(key) {
      var index = arr.indexOf(key);
      if (index == -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
   }
 }

 var result = insertName();
 exports.validName = validName;
```

File2.js

```
  var file1 = require("./File1.js");
  var name = "josh";
  var verify = file1.validName(name);

 if(verify) {
    console.log("Valid name");
 } else {
      console.log("Error");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use global.(name) = (value)

Example :

**main.js**

```
global.foo = 1;
require('./mod.js').show();
```

**mod.js**

```
module.exports = {
    show : function(){
        console.log(global.foo); // which prints "1"
    }
}
```