# How to retain global variable value

Tags: node.js

I am using global variable arr [] in one file called File1.js. When I run the file in node, its working.But using Cluster module in node its not working. Any help on this will be really helpful.

```
//Cluster.js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var workers = process.env.WORKERS || require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    winston.log("info", "start cluster with %s workers" + workers);
    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
        var options = { exec: "File1.js" };
        cluster.setupMaster(options);
        var worker = cluster.fork().process;
        winston.log("info", "worker %s started." + worker.pid);
        worker.on('death', function (worker) {
            winston.log("debug", "worker " + worker.pid + " died. restart...");
            cluster.fork();
        });
        worker.on('message', function (message) {
            // error in message.err
            winston.log("error", "Error Message: " + message.err);
        });
    }
}

if (cluster.isWorker) {
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
        // tell the master there is an error
        //process.send({ err: err });
        winston.log("error", "Error Message: " + err.stack);
    });
}
```

}

I will be using node Cluster.js which will call [File1.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074604/how-to-declare-and-access-global-variable?noredirect=1#comment37126820_24074604)

Comment: You should post the cluster code. How are you using this in cluster.

Comment: I am affraid that `arr` is not a global variable.